# Remove all classes except first using pure JS

Tags: javascript, loops, html

I am trying to remove all classes except the fist one.

html:

```
<div class="note">1</div>
<div class="note">1</div>
<div class="note">1</div>
<div class="note">1</div>
```

Js:

```
for (var item of document.querySelectorAll("div.note(not:first-of-type"))) {
    item.classList.remove('note');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:not(:first-of-type)`:

```js
for (var item of document.querySelectorAll("div.note:not(:first-of-type)")) {
    item.classList.remove('note');
}
```

```css
.note {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">1</div>
<div class="note">2</div>
<div class="note">3</div>
<div class="note">4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop and check the index like so:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.note")).forEach((div, ind) => {
    if (ind != 0) {
        div.classList.remove("note");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use for loop also:

```
var array = document.querySelectorAll("div.note");
for(let i =1; i<array.length; i++){
    array[i].classList.remove('note')
}
```